# When i Click on a pinpoint it should open a alertdialog in Android Maps

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

I have a Main Activity class which loads the current Location of the user. There is a another class which extends ItemizedOverlay. This class takes care of placing a pinpoint.
I have one more class which fetches nearby ATM location.. So i use a for loop for placing pinpoints at all nearby atm location. 
I want my app to pop up when i tap on a particular pin. Showing vicinity of that place.

```
for(int i=0; i < placeName.length;i++){
nearbylatitude= (int) (lati[i]*1E6);
nearbylongitude=(int) (longi[i]*1E6);
Log.e("Location", nearbylatitude+"\t \t"+ nearbylongitude);
GeoPoint myLocation_nearby_place= new GeoPoint(nearbylatitude, nearbylongitude);    
OverlayItem overlayPlaces=new             OverlayItem(myLocation_nearby_place,placeName[i],vicinity[i]);
custom_Places=new CustomPinpoint(drawable_places,     MainMapActivity.this);
    custom_Places.addPinPoints(overlayPlaces);
     overlayList.add(custom_Places);

    }
```

This is the for loop which places pin point at nearby Location. I know that there is a Method onTap() with ItemizedOverlay... But i dnt know when to call that function and how to retreive which pin is tapped.

Need a urgent help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

public OverlayItem(GeoPoint point,
                   java.lang.String title,
                   java.lang.String snippet)
Parameters:
point - Position of the item.
title - Title text.
snippet - Snippet text.

```
OverlayItem currentOverlay = new OverlayItem(CurrLocGeoPoint(),"Text for bubble","");
```

Comment: I have the pinpoint in on the map... i want to find the Lat and longi of the pinpoint which is taped.?

Comment: I got it with doing with onTap(int index) but for all pins its showing index 0...? I guess every pin should have unique index..

Comment: i found the answer ... it was by using index and geting the value from ArrayList for that particular index..